# How can I display an Image in an NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nscell

I have an NSTableView that is populating with my data source.

My data model has a URL to an image.

I would like to display an image next to some text in every cell of my NSTableView. Basically like a twitter client, image on the left, with some text on the right.

I am not sure how to do this Cocoa? I am familiar with the process in Cocoa-Touch (by subclassing UITableViewCell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a frame on each cell, and draw a picture in that.  Refer here:

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284

Answer (score 1):

You should drag `NSImageCell` onto the column you want your image to be displayed. Then adjust the value of the image via image cell bindings pane.

Comment: i am doing everything without a nib. how can i achieve this in code?

Comment: return NSTableRow populated with needed cells in NSTableView delegate method